# как вывести из текстового файла число (время) ? java

Tags: java, логирование

У меня есть следующий код, из файла (Logs.txt, [https://imgur.com/a/7pZyg5t(скришнот)сам](https://imgur.com/a/7pZyg5t(%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82)%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC) текст https://pastebin.com/ZwJt4dSj)  берёт какое-либо число, мне нужно чтобы это число было [12:25:23]
и разбить его на [var1:var2:var3]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class MathMethod {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    String UserName = "Арслан";
    System.out.println("Привет" + " " + UserName + ", " + "Программа начинает свою работу. Получаю все переменные");
    
    String Zombie = "Королевский зомби";
    String Slime = "Сточный слизень";
    String Spider = "Матка";
    String Cow = "Коровка из Коровёнки";
    String Yeti = "Йети";
    String Levik = "Левиафан";
    String Fish = "Хранитель подводного мира";
    String Ghast = "Небесный владыка";

    String ZOMBIE_BOSS = Zombie;
    String SLIME_BOSS = Slime;
    String SPIDER_BOSS = Spider;
    String COW_BOSS = Cow;
    String YETI_BOSS = Yeti;
    String LEVIK_BOSS = Levik;
    String FISH_BOSS = Fish;
    String GHAST_BOSS = Ghast;
    {
        String[] Bosses = new String[] {ZOMBIE_BOSS, SLIME_BOSS, SPIDER_BOSS, COW_BOSS, YETI_BOSS, LEVIK_BOSS, FISH_BOSS, GHAST_BOSS};
        
        String lineFromFile;    
        String s = File.separator;
        //Чтобы тестить
        String path = s+ "Users" +s+ UserName +s+ "eclipse-workspace" +s+ "BossCheck" +s+ "src" +s+ "Boss" +s+ "Logs.txt";
        //Чтобы пустить в работу программу String path = s+ "Users" +s+ UserName +s+ "AppData" +s+ "Roaming" +s+ ".vimeworld" +s+ "minigames" +s+ "logs" +s+ "latest.txt";
        
       //All CoolDowns in minutes. If need seconds = bossCD * 60
        
        int ZombieCD = 20;
        int SlimeCD = 45;
        int SpiderCD = 90;
        int CowCD = 150;
        int YetiCD = 180;
        int LevikCD = 150;
        int FishCD = 360;
        int GhastCD = 480;
        
        
        System.out.println("Я получил все переменные, начинаю получать информацию с логов (latest.txt) \n");
        
        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader
                (new FileInputStream(path), "Windows-1251")) {
            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
                while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                    lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    
                    int bossIndex = -1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Bosses.length; i++) {
                        if (lineFromFile.contains(Bosses[i])) {
                            bossIndex = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (bossIndex != -1) {
                        String[] str3 = lineFromFile.split("[" + "]");
                        String[] str2 = lineFromFile.split(Bosses[bossIndex] + " " + "был повержен за ");
                        if (str2.length > 1) {
                            str2 = str2[1].split(" ");
                            var time = Integer.parseInt(str2[0]);
                            
                            if(str3.length > 1) {
                                    str3 = str3[1].split(" ");
                                    var time2 = Integer.parseInt(str3[0]);
                            
                            System.out.println("Информацию с логов получил, начинаю математические расчёты. 2+2=... \n");
                            
                            System.out.println("Отлично, держи: \n");
                            if(Bosses.length == 8) {
                                System.out.println("Королевский Зомби" + " " + LocalTime.now().plusMinutes(ZombieCD + time / 60));
                            }
                            if(Bosses.length == 8) {
                                System.out.println("Сточный слизень" + " " + LocalTime.now().plusMinutes(SlimeCD + time / 60));
                            }
                            if(Bosses.length == 8) {
                                System.out.println("Матка" + " " + LocalTime.now().plusHours(SpiderCD / 60 + time / 60));
                            }
                            if(Bosses.length == 8) {
                                System.out.println("Коровка из Коровёнки" + " " + LocalTime.now().plusHours(CowCD / 60 + time / 60));
                            }
                            if(Bosses.length == 8) {
                                System.out.println("Йети" + " " + LocalTime.now().plusHours(YetiCD / 60 + time / 60));
                            }
                            if(Bosses.length == 8) {
                                System.out.println("Левиафан" + " " + LocalTime.now().plusHours(LevikCD / 60 + time / 60));
                            }
                            if(Bosses.length == 8) {
                                System.out.println("Хранитель подводного Мира" + " " + LocalTime.now().plusHours(FishCD / 60 + time / 60));
                            }
                            if(Bosses.length == 8) {
                                System.out.println("Небесный Владыка" + " " + LocalTime.now().plusHours(GhastCD / 60 + time / 60 ) + "\n");
                            }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();{
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: У вас есть какой то файл и вам что то нужно. Это понятно. Вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Как из файла Logs.txt получить и вывести [12:25:23] и разбить его числа на переменные, абсолютно любые, надеюсь понятно

Comment: У вас 2 опции : попробовать руками разделить строки или использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: Как это руками разделить?

Comment: Вы можете использовать метод строки substring, чтобы вытащить прдстроку с индексами с первого по девятый. А после использовать метод split по символу двоеточия, чтобы время разделить на часы, минуты и секунды. Оба метода являются простейшими операциями со строкой, вы можете из за две секунды загуглить.

Comment: А способ с регулярными выражениями?

Comment: Это чуть более сложный и медленный способ, зато более гибкий. Вам надо будет составить регулярное выражение и проверять каждую строку на соответствие этому выражению. Само регулярное выражение будет несложное, но вам для его составления надо изучить хотя бы основы языка регулярных выражений.

Comment: Я уже сделал руками.
Как можно привести то-что я сделал 
                                String hour = bossLog.substring(1,3);
                                System.out.println(hour);
                                String min = bossLog.substring(4,6);
                                System.out.println(min);
                                String sec = bossLog.substring(7,9);
                                System.out.println(sec);
к целочисленному значению, т.е. чтобы можно было складывать каждую String переменную к int переменной ?

Comment: Поиск этой [информации](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5585800/312041) реально занимает миллисекунду. Не тратье чужое время на то, что сами прекрасно можете найти.

Comment: Извините, спасибо.

Comment: Чтобы разбить время на 3 переменные, поищите про метод split() у String. Вы получите массив из 3 цифр.